# Find Top K elements in WindowedStream - Flink

Tags: scala, stream, streaming, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am pretty new in the world of Streams and I am facing some issues in my first try.

What I would like to do is to find the Top K element in the `window: WindowdStream` below.
I tried to implement my own function but not sure how it actually works.

Seems that doesn't print anything

May you have any hint?

```
val parsedStream: DataStream[(String, Response)] = stream
      .mapWith(_.decodeOption[Response])
      .filter(_.isDefined)
      .map { record =>
        (
          s"${record.get.group.group_country}, ${record.get.group.group_city}",
          record.get
        )
      }

val topLocations = parsedStream
      .keyBy(_._1)
      .timeWindow(Time.days(7))
      .process(new SortByCountFunction)
```

SortByCountFunction

```
class SortByCountFunction
    extends ProcessWindowFunction[(String, Response), MeetUpLocationWindow, String, TimeWindow] {

    override def process(key: String,
                         context: Context,
                         elements: Iterable[(String, Response)],
                         out: Collector[MeetUpLocationWindow]): Unit = {

      val count: Map[String, Iterable[(String, Response)]] = elements.groupBy(_._1)

      val locAndCount: Seq[MeetUpLocation] = count.toList.map(tmp => {
        val location: String = tmp._1
        val meetUpList: Iterable[(String, Response)] = tmp._2
        MeetUpLocation(location, tmp._2.size, meetUpList.map(_._2).toList)
      })

      val output: List[MeetUpLocation] = locAndCount.sortBy(tup => tup.count).take(20).toList

      val windowEnd = context.window.getEnd

      out.collect(MeetUpLocationWindow(windowEnd, output))
    }
  }

case class MeetUpLocationWindow(endTs: Long, locations: List[MeetUpLocation])

case class MeetUpLocation(location: String, count: Int, meetUps: List[Response])
```

Answer (score 1):

When your Flink DataStream job fails to produce any output, the usual suspects are:

- the job doesn't call execute() on the StreamExecutionEnvironment (e.g., `env.execute()`)
- the job doesn't have a sink attached (e.g., `TopLocations.print()`)
- the job is meant to use event time, but the Watermarks aren't set up correctly or an idle source is preventing the watermarks from advancing
- the job is writing to the taskmanager logs, but no one noticed
- the serializer for the output type produces no output

Without more information it's difficult to guess which of these might be the problem in this case.

Comment: I think that the problem is in `SortByCountFunction` but not able to detect it.

Comment: It appears to me that the SortByCountFunction will always collect something to the output, even if it's the wrong result. If absolutely nothing is being printed by the job, then something else must be wrong as well.